# Helper.getWritableDatabase() function

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm working on my first SQLite database app and because I'm stuck for a long time I decided to ask about it online.

I have trouble with running the application I that have written, because of the function: `Helper.getWritableDatabase();`

without it, it runs fine.

My database indeed created when I take a look at the Data/Data/projects source at the DDMS

Code:

**The Symptom class:**

```
public class Symptom {

long symptomId;
String name;
long details;


public Symptom(long symptomId, String name, long details) {
    super();
    this.symptomId = symptomId;
    this.name = name;
    this.details = details;
}

public Symptom() {}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(long details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public long getSymptomId() {
    return symptomId;
}

public void setSymptomId(long symptomId) {
    this.symptomId = symptomId;
};
```

}

**The SymptomOpenHelper class:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class SymptomOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public static final String DATABASENAME="Symptom.db";
public static final String TABLE_SYMPTOM="tblSymptom";
public static final int DATABASEVERSION = 1;

public static final String COLUMN_ID="symptomId";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME="name";
public static final String COLUMN_DETAILS="details";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + TABLE_SYMPTOM + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME +"VARCHAR," +COLUMN_DETAILS +"VARCHAR" + ");";


public SymptomOpenHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);

}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM);
    Log.i("data" ,"Table sypmpton created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int NewVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + TABLE_SYMPTOM);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

**The MainActivity code:**

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SymptomOpenHelper sHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    sHelper =new SymptomOpenHelper(this);
            // The trouble-maker line:

    database=sHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

According to the android simulator: "Unfortunately, The_app_name has stopped"

**The LogCat:**

> 12-31 19:55:37.744: E/Trace(924): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   12-31 19:55:38.964: E/SQLiteLog(924): (1) near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
>   12-31 19:55:38.994: D/AndroidRuntime(924): Shutting down VM
>   12-31 19:55:38.994: W/dalvikvm(924): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idiagnostician1/com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSymptom (symptomId INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR, details VARCHAR);
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSymptom (symptomId INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR, details VARCHAR);
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.example.idiagnostician1.SymptomOpenHelper.onCreate(SymptomOpenHelper.java:30)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   12-31 19:55:39.124: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  ... 11 more
>   12-31 19:55:44.334: E/Trace(986): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   12-31 19:55:44.624: E/SQLiteLog(986): (1) near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
>   12-31 19:55:44.624: D/AndroidRuntime(986): Shutting down VM
>   12-31 19:55:44.634: W/dalvikvm(986): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idiagnostician1/com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSymptom (symptomId INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR, details VARCHAR);
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblSymptom (symptomId INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name VARCHAR, details VARCHAR);
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.example.idiagnostician1.SymptomOpenHelper.onCreate(SymptomOpenHelper.java:30)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   12-31 19:55:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(986):  ... 11 more

Comment: can you show us your logcat.

Comment: your query create table has problem. add space after `if not exist  `

Comment: worked? if not need stacktrace again

Comment: @Jimmy, that's the answer. You might want to post it as such.

Comment: not yet.. It's still stuck

Comment: what does it say now? You have missed spaces in other places of the same query . fix them as well. Otherwise, your getWritableDatabase() seems legit to me. Should be causing problem

Comment: You mean what the LogCat shows now?

Comment: Can you try the query added in my answer below.

Comment: I wrote the following query and the results are just the same:
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_SYMPTOM + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME +" VARCHAR," +COLUMN_DETAILS +" VARCHAR" + ");";

Comment: do a clean build and try it. Because it is not reflected there. If you are using emulator, restart emulator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ComponentInfo{com.example.idiagnostician1/com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTtblSymptom": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTtblSymptom(symptomIdINTEGER PRIMART KEY
```

Based on this information in you logcat, you have problem in your query CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM.
You need to append space after `NOT EXIST` . example:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST " + TABLE_SYMPTOM ...
```

instead of

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST" + TABLE_SYMPTOM
```

check your query correctly and you will see you have made this mistake all over the queries. Add spaces in other required places as well in same query.
Try this query :

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SYMPTOM + " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME +" VARCHAR, " +COLUMN_DETAILS +" VARCHAR" + ");"
```

Comment: @YanivGK restart your emulator and do a clean build. The change is just not reflected in your query for some reason.

Comment: @YanivGK now update your query and replace `EXIST` with `EXISTS` and it should work. have fun

Comment: By "clean build" do you mean "clean up"?
because it still didn't change anything.

Comment: Your query needs `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT EXIST`.

Comment: It changed something, but then failed again :/

Comment: now update log again . what does it says? Its probably another problem . You may wanna post another question. Unfortunately, I can not invite you to chat either because of your reputation.

Comment: @YanivGK your query is so  messed up. i would suggest you to rewrite it. Or for now, just try `PRIMARY` instead of `PRIMART` and see what happens next

Comment: I see.. then at least can you tell me what is the main problem? So I could open a proper question.

Comment: @YanivGK did you change spelling of `PRIMART` to `PRIMARY` ?

Comment: Oh lord, that it!!
It actually work! Thank you so much.

Comment: I marked, Thank you again.
I wish I could vote for your answer, but my reputation is too low.. ><

Comment: Thats cool. I don't think you can vote and mark as answer anyway. Have fun coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM is wrong

For

```
COLUMN_ID + "INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
```

You need add a space:

```
COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMART KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
```

The CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM should changed as below:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SYMPTOM="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_SYMPTOM + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME +" VARCHAR, " +COLUMN_DETAILS +" VARCHAR" + ");";
```

Comment: @YanivGK upload the new log please